# Update na tabela da base de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho este código para fazer `updat`e do campo `estad`o como concluído e ser o único campo que pode ser editado:

```
<?php  

    $servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
    $username = "xxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxxxxx";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $conn->set_charset('utf8');

    $result_cursos = "SELECT centrodb.RegistoManutencao.Id,
           DataRegisto,
           Pedido,
           Outro,
           Descricao,
           Funcionario,
           Imagem,
           Tratamento,
           Estado

    FROM centrodb.RegistoManutencao LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.InfoLuvas

    ON centrodb.InfoLuvas.Id = centrodb.RegistoManutencao.Colaborador

    WHERE Estado IS NULL OR Estado <> 'Concluído';";
        $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

    $tabela1 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

    $tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

    $tabela1 .= '<tr>';

    $tabela1 .='<thead>';

    $tabela1 .= '<tr>';

    $tabela1 .= '<th>Nº Registo</th>';

    $tabela1 .= '<th>Data</th>';

    $tabela1 .= '<th>Pedido</th>';

    $tabela1 .= '<th>Outro Local</th>';

    $tabela1 .= '<th>Descrição</th>';

    $tabela1 .= '<th>Colaborador</th>';

    $tabela1 .= '<th>Estado</th>';

    $tabela1 .= '</tr>';

    $tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

    $tabela1 .='<tbody>';

        while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

    $tabela1 .= '<tr>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Pedido'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Outro'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Descricao'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Funcionario'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Id[]" value="'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'"></td>';;

    $tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
    }
    $tabela1 .= '</tr>';

    $tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

    $tabela1 .= '</table>';

    $tabela1 .= '</div>';

    echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";

    echo $tabela1;

    echo "<input type='submit' name='registar' value='Registo'>";
    echo "</form>";


    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";



    ?>

    <?php  
    if(isset($_POST['registar']))
    {
    $servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
    $username = "xxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxxx";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $conn->set_charset('utf8');

    $id= $_POST['Id'];
    $estado= $_POST['Estado'];

        $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoManutencao SET Estado='$estado' WHERE Id=".$Id); 


    }
    ?>
```

Mas quando faz o `update` à tabela, os campos ficam em branco....

Comment: Preciso ver o formulário HTML pra ter certeza da causa do problema o se realmente o valor esta indo pro método `POST`

Comment: Mas isto é independente do formulário onde é feito o `insert`. Aqui mostro a consulta e na tabela da consulta quero fazer o `update` do campo estado com o valor concluído

Comment: Não entendi qual é o problema `não me faz o update na tabela da coluna checkbox com o nome estado:`

Comment: esse verbo está correto? `registar` ...   `Registo`

Comment: e como se recupera valores via Post fora do formulario?

Comment: Então não é possível inserir o valor da Coluna Estado na tabela onde faço o registo com o formulário? Eu pensei que assim recuperava os valores ao utilizar o Post

Comment: Tem que colocar tudo dentro do formulario (inputs, select, etcc, com name) para poder submeter e recuperar via POST

Comment: Pode colocar só um exemplo?

Comment: Os dados da tabela poderão ser editados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo comentário, `Eles não podem ser editados, só a coluna estado,` e como a coluna `Estado` tem valor invariável `value="Concluído"`

**acredito que dessa forma atende o que você quer:**

**fazer update na coluna `estado` do(s) `id(s)` marcado(s).**

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{

$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$registro = $_POST['Id'];

foreach($registro as $value) { 
    $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoDiario SET Estado='concluido' WHERE Id=" . $value); 
}
............
............

while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

    $tabela1 .= '<tr>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';


    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Dia'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['TipoRefeicao'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Refeicao'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Hora'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Motivo'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Sugestao'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Colaborador'].'</td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Id[]" value="'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'"></td>';

    $tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
}
}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';


    echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
     echo $tabela1;

    echo "<input type='submit' name='registar' value='Registar'>";

    echo "</form>";
?>
```

> `$registro = $_POST['Id'];` vai retornar um array dos `checkboxes` marcados vez que os `names` dos checkboxes contem `[]` (colchetes) apos os `names`

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Id[]" value="'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'"></td>';
```

> Dai é só iterar o array com o update

```
foreach($registro as $value) { 
    $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoDiario SET Estado='concluido' WHERE Id=" . $value);
}
```

---

### Com input type="radio", Concluído ou Pendente

**Substitua essa linha**

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Id[]" value="'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'"></td>';
```

**por essa linha**

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "Id['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="Concluido">Concluído  <input type="radio" name= "Id['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="Pendente"> Pendente</td>';
```

**e no PHP substitua o `foreach`**

```
foreach ($registro as $Id => $estado) {

    $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoDiario SET Estado='".$estado."' Where Id='".$Id."'"); 

}
```

Comment: Primeiro vc constrói uma tabela com as colunas preenchidas com os dados do banco, correto? Dai vc quer o que? que esses dados sejam enviados para UPDATE? Mas eles poderão ser editados ou não?

Comment: Eles não podem ser editados, só a coluna estado. Fiz como o exemplo e mantive toda a estrutura como tenho na pergunta, mas não fez o `update` na  tabela

Comment: depois do update coloca `echo $sql1;` e veja o que retorna

Comment: Retorna isto, `UPDATE RegistoDiario SET Id = '11', DataRegisto = '2018-02-09', Dia = 'Sexta-Feira', TipoRefeicao = 'Normal', Refeicao = 'Almoço', Hora = '12:00', Motivo = '', Sugestao = '', Colaborador = 'Fátima', Estado = '' WHERE Id = '11'`, mas o id que estou a editar é o **1**. Quero que ele só coloque como concluído na coluna estado os que eu colocar o visto. É possível? Da forma que está, está assumir o último `Id`, mas mesmo colocando o visto no último ele não faz o update dessa linha

Comment: Na tabela retorna todos os ids, desde o 1 ao 11. Depois coloco o visto na linha do `id=1` e no `echo` do `update` ele mostra que fez o WHERE Id = '11', mas se colocar o visto nessa linha ele não faz o `update` na mesma a essa linha

Comment: Rapaz, vou criar uma tabela e reproduzir no meu servidor, pode me dar a tabela?

Comment: Coloquei a tabela em cima na pergunta

Comment: deu ruim no meu banco `Script line: 1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`CREATE TABLE `RegistoDiario` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Dat' at line 1
`

Comment: Isso o que significa?

Comment: Significa que criei uma tabela manualmente, depois vejo o que é esse erro

Comment: Já descobri o problema, vou consertar aqui e depois edito a resposta

Comment: OK, depois podes dizer onde estava o problema para eu perceber onde estava a errar?

Comment: pretendia o mesmo que me ajudaste a fazer com `input type="checkbox"`, mas agora pretendia que fosse com um `input type="radio"`, onde pudesse colocar ou **Concluído ou Pendente**

Comment: @Junior acrescido na resposta com  `input type="radio"`

Comment: funcionou, mas agora tenho outro problema, editei a pergunta

Comment: @Junior cada caso deve ser postado em uma nova pergunta para que a resposta não fique sem entendimento

Comment: Eu editei esta pergunta para não estar a postar nova pergunta sobre o mesmo tema, mas não volta a acontecer. Devo voltar a colocar a pergunta como tinha? Então para me responder faço uma pergunta nova?

Comment: @Junior, exato, veja que a minha resposta ficou sem sentido para a pergunta editada. Postando como nova pergunta, outros usuarios poderão responder tambem

Comment: já fiz a alteração e já criei uma nova pergunta....e obrigado pela explicação da situação de alterar a pergunta

Answer (score -1):

Tente fechar a TAG `input`:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Estado" value="Concluído"</td>';
```

Dessa maneira:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Estado" value="Concluído" /></td>';
```

Comment: Não resolveu, não faz o `update` na tabela

Comment: Agora que eu vi, a linha do Checkbox está fora do `FORM`, estou certo?

Comment: sim, a linha do checkbox só aprece quando mostro a consulta na tabela e quando faço a inserção no form só existem estes campos: Id,
       `DataRegisto,
       Dia,
       TipoRefeicao,
       Refeicao,
       Hora,
       Motivo,
       Sugestao,
       Colaborador`